# List view with array

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a Android studio project with a list view, that i want to fill with a array names but i can´t do it

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
 // the array that i want to fill in listview
public String[]nombreSecciones = {"Perfil", "Juego", "Instrucciones", "Info"};
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/secciones"
    android:entries="@array/nombreSecciones"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

android:entries dont fill the listview with the items of the Arraylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
public String[] nombreSecciones = {"Perfil", "Juego", "Instrucciones", "Info"};
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.secciones);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, nombreSecciones);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
}
```

Comment: i have a problem with listView eclipse said
"cannot resolve symbol 'listView'

Comment: add this line: `import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;`

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your array inside a XML file. In your case, it should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="nombreSecciones">
        <item>Perfil</item>
        <item>Juego</item>
        <item>Instrucciones</item>
        <item>Info</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Save this file as res/values/arrays.xml and you're good to go.

If you want to have a non-static list of items, you have to implement an Adapter for the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nombreSecciones); 
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```